# In my plugin when i call select page is blank

Tags: plugins

i have problem:
In my plugin directory I have two files:

- `gen.php`
- `open.php`

When I redirect from `gen.php` to `open.php` and I use select in `open.php`

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_ogloszenia_kupione");
```

My file won't open I use:

```
$fp = fopen(trim(trim($id)),"wb");

fwrite($fp,$content);
fwrite($fp, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));
fopen(trim(trim($id)),"r");
fclose($fp);
//End 4
//5 - Otwarcie pliku



if (file_exists(trim($id))) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename(trim($id)));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(trim($id)));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile(trim($id));
    exit;
}
```

But when I delete select everything work Good.

So why does select cause this mess?

Comment: Are you sure you are in WordPress context? with that I mean $wpdb is available?

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: If you're calling the file directly you are not in a WordPress context, and thus it's functions are not available to your script.

Comment: i use thips from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217098/how-to-include-wpdb-in-wordpress-plugin anywhey thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to load files that will make $wpdb and other WordPress function available in the context. You can include some php files to emulate the WordPress context

```
include_once('../../../wp-config.php');
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
include_once('../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');

$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "posts");
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: ok i check this.